# Need to display data coming from web service as chart data points in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, charts

I have a jquery chart where I have data points like this:

```
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                        {
                            title: {
                                text: "MONTHLY STATISTICS"
                            },
                            axisX: {
                                title: "Axis X Title"
                            },
                            axisY: {
                                title: "Total Number"
                            },

                            data: [
                            {
                                type: "column",

                                dataPoints: [ 
                    { x: 10, y: 6, label:"Apple"},
                    { x: 20, y: 2, label:"Mango"},
                    { x: 30, y: 5, label:"Orange"},
                    { x: 40, y: 7, label:"Banana"},
                    { x: 50, y: 1, label:"PineApple"},
                    { x: 60, y: 5, label:"Pears"},    
                    { x: 70, y: 5, label:"Grapes"},
                    { x: 80, y: 2, label:"Lychee"},
                    { x: 80, y: 2, label:"Jackfruit"}


                                ]
                            }
                            ]
                        });

                        chart.render();
```

I have a web-service where I am getting json format data and I am storing that in a string variable s in chart data-points format.Code for receiving  data from web-service and converting it to chart data-points format is as follows:

```
 success: function(datas)
                {
                    var points = datas.d;
                    var s = "";
                    $.each(points, function (index, Info) {

                        s = s + "{x:" + Info.x + ", y:" + Info.y + ", label:\"" + Info.label + "\"},";


                    });
```

Now problem I am facing is that when I give string 's' as data-points value it doesnot work.
My full code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSent = "{roll:" + 1 + ",name:\"" + "Mubashir\"}";
        $.ajax({

            type: "Post",
            url: "WebServices.aspx/LoadStatistics",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(datas)
            {
                var points = datas.d;
                var s = "";
                $.each(points, function (index, Info) {

                    s = s + "{x:" + Info.x + ", y:" + Info.y + ", label:\"" + Info.label + "\"},";


                });


                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                    {
                        title: {
                            text: "MONTHLY STATISTICS"
                        },
                        axisX: {
                            title: "Axis X Title"
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            title: "Total Number"
                        },

                        data: [
                        {
                            type: "column",

                            dataPoints: [ 

                          s

                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    });

                    chart.render();



        }
            ,


            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);

                $("#LoginRecords").text('No information Available!');

            }




        });


    });





</script>
<script src="tabs/js/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

If I remove s variable and insert dummy data-points it works fine. Now my question at the end is how to use data coming from web-service as chart data-points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create a string out of the server response. To iterate over the server response you need to parse the JSON.

Try something like this:

```
var yourDataPoints = [];
$.each(points, function (index, Info) {
    yourDataPoints.push({
        x: Info.x,
        y: Info.y,
        label: Info.label
    });
});
```

And later assign your `yourDataPoints` array.

```
data: [
    { 
        type: 'column',
        dataPoints: yourDataPoints
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you describe/show the error? A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Worked nicely ...Actually I had made changes in code which was creating errors....Thx @localgost

Answer (score 0):

try this:
"dataPoints: jQuery.parseJSON(s)"

dataPoints expected array of json object and in your code "s" is string,so please convert into Json object first and it will work